# How to set toolbar title when a text view hide from screen?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

How to implement that action which is shown in image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MluU2.jpg

Comment: which action you want?

Comment: @jawadmalik when page scroll and title hide it goes to the toolbar

Answer (score 1):

Use this piece of code to hide your layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- Your Remaining Code -->

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: you need to  make a toolbar like layout and add the item that you want and then you can hide and show the visibility according to your choice by using if else of particular textview or images.

Comment: @vishalsharma of course but I don't know how should I do this

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `collapsingToolbar` layout. The material design example is found [here](https://material.io/develop/android/components/collapsing-toolbar-layout/) but of significance is the below snippet

```
 <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
      app:expandedTitleGravity="top"
      app:expandedTitleMarginStart="@dimen/shrine_toolbar_offset_start"
      app:expandedTitleMarginTop="@dimen/shrine_toolbar_offset_top"
      app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/shrine_toolbar_image_offset_top"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
        app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.5"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/AppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/shrine_toolbar_collapsed_height"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
   </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```